# Siri Windows API: Make Windows PC print a document via voice command to Siri HomePod

Tags: windows, siri

I have a Apple ecosystem in my apartment along with a **Windows PC**.

I am wondering whether Apple offers making a Windows PC on my WiFi network controllable by my Siri enabled HomePod?

If I could make my PC a HomeKit device, for example, I should in theory, be able to teach Siri to carry out predefined Actions on my Windows PC (for example, printing a page to my printer from my Windows pc)

"Hey Siri, print the page I am browsing on my PC".

Has Apple provided an API for this kind of thing? Or not (yet)? Does anyone know of any other non-Apple ways to do this?  (e.g., something similar to [this](https://thereallycoolstuff.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/using-siri-to-control-your-computer/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Workflow](http://workflow.is) on iOS allows you to perform web service calls and send commands over SSH. The Siri shortcuts functionality coming in iOS 12 *appears* to be based at least partially on Workflow’s technology (Apple aqui-hired the developers.)

As to whether all of Workflow’s functionality will appear in Siri Shortcuts at some point, I have no information either way.

Even if it does, it would be up to you to provide some sort of endpoint/plumbing on the Windows side to actually pull this off. You’d be fully on your own.

Comment: I'll check it out. This is more along the lines of what I was looking for, and SSH and plumbing shouldn't be an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering whether Apple offers making a PC on my WiFi controllable by my Siri HomePod?

**No**.

> Has Apple provided an API for this kind of thing? Or not (yet)?

**No**.

Comment: That's a very short answer ;) Has apple allowed any of this on MacOS? I am assuming that Apple will move in this general direction at least with MacOS, and, if they don't fear Microsoft, allow Microsoft et. al to use this as well in months (hopefully not years) to come...

Comment: There's nothing much to add :) macOS has Siri built-in but doesn't yet support integration with 3rd party apps (as far as I know), just iOS and watchOS. No comments regarding your other statement.

Comment: Thanks. Are you employed by Apple? just kidding ;) I have expanded the question to ask for other ways that would at least in theory allow some basic control over a PC via Siri.

Comment: That could be an ingenious programming "hack". However, as per your original question and the scope of discussion on Ask Different, there's no standard way to achieve the desired.

Comment: Agree. I'll keep the question open for a little while though to see if there are other ways floating around the internet. If Apple has not closed off ALL doors, there must be several ways to at least get Siri talkin to a PC on an API/Coding level OR a "Hack" - allthough I wouldn't call it that, its more of an "internet of things" thing for me -  via other systems, (e.g. google in the unconfirmed example I posted), I'll explore a bit further too, and see if there is anything that is practical.

Comment: Is the scope of Askdifferent only to use Apple, without any external services and workaround such as gmail, in this case?

Comment: Apple hardware, software and services, along with third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products. Code level and software development questions are off-tpoic with a few exceptions. Details here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, was unaware of that. Anyway, the above mentioned gmail note thing works, just confirmed. Will still mark your answer as correct, and wait a while until Apple allows me to officially control my PC via Siri and/or HomeKit. Or I will switch to a Mac ;) In the meantime, I will set up my PC to print pages for me on Voice Command using Siri in the way described, further info here: https://github.com/theraspberryguy/SiriControl-System. Should also work with a custom script in several other ways (outlook notes, and maybe even other cloud-syncing apps)